# Server-side mobile infrastructure for native iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, backend, server-side, multi-model-database

I am looking for storage and database infrastructure that can help me save and retrieve information from my Swift codebase app. But I have no experience with server-side code. Requirements have no need for full blown backend solution and REST API. My application is proof of concept where I would use Cocoa frameworks in Xcode. After a some research I am missing information regarding to cost management of few popular services. I am new to iOS development and would like to learn a simple server-side component, but at the same time I do not want to pay fees for production usage.

I am looking for service to achieve this goal, with the following features:

- can save location coordinates form app
- can save images taken from app
- can retrieve location and images from storage

I like Parse Bitnami, IBM Bluemix, Azure App but it fails in a critical way because I have to pay for it without being profitable to start with.

Regarding IBM Bluemix I see it is again 90 days trial free. Does anyone have experience with price after trial? As well know Azure App is also an option but I am hoping for real-time DB or cloud DB solutions. Amazon is charging services of 4-5$ per month on a free tier and I would like to leave them.[1 year free AWS tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbAYW.png)

[image: parse server vs firebase]

Comment: Have you considered firebase?

Comment: If you don't want to invest in backend server, go with Firebase and if your target audience is higher then don't relay on Firebase only, Have a backend for sure. Because `Backend is backbone of Applications` :)

Comment: Yes, realtime Database or cloud solution sounds great. I am wondering is there any other as well with fast learning curve? Thanks. @amir what backend would you recommend?

Comment: @Marina there are lots of recommended backend server and programming languages for serving but it depends on your App requirement. what is feasible for you. You can go with `AWS AppSync` as well or Java, MongoDB, PHP with Socket (for real time sync)

Comment: Great, thanks  I will look into AWS AppSync solution too.

Comment: @Marina Happy coding :)

Comment: Also you can check out Parse. The commercial version shut down a few months ago but there's a community version out there.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Parse on Heroku for small fee and Storage:
496 MB it doesn’t have an easy implementation for real-time data changes on the server. Backendless seems solid solution maybe https://backendless.com/pricing/backendless-cloud-pricing/

Comment: Really helpful isights also here at raywenderlich-   they never mention Firebase 
  https://www.raywenderlich.com/2819-how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more

Comment: @Marina You can have a closer look at the Azure Services. Especially for the App Services as well as Cosmos DB there are free plans available that help to get you started. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cosmos-db/?utm_source=Azure_for_iOS_WWDC_Page&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=appcenter_WWDC

Comment: Hey @jimmy this looks promissing Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: :) at the end i want to choose openSource server: https://blog.sashido.io/five-reasons-to-choose-open-source-parse-server-and-sashido-for-your-backend/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered CloudKit? It is a part of the iOS development toolbox and is free for up to 10 million active users. It is somewhat limited but should be enough for what you are trying to make. Also, it's made and hosted by apple and they have a good library (CloudKit) that is already available inside Xcode.

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/

Comment: As well CloudKit containers can’t be deleted, so I won’t be able to “turn off” CloudKit if the cost suddenly blows out.

Comment: Users required to use iCloud, but the storage is impressive.